# Microsoft Graph API with Simple-OAuth2 and Client Credentials Flow

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to log users with Client Credentials Flow with Simple-OAuth2 in a NodeJS website.

My routes/index.js is this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var authHelper = require('../helpers/auth');

router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  let parms = { title: 'Home', active: { home: true } };
  const accessToken = await authHelper.accessToken;
  res.render('index', parms);
});

module.exports = router;
```

And my auth.js is this:

```
const credentials = {
  client: {
    id: process.env.APP_ID,
    secret: process.env.APP_PASSWORD,
  },
  auth: {
    tokenHost: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
    authorizePath: "common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
    tokenPath: "common/oauth2/v2.0/token",
  }
};
const oauth2 = require('simple-oauth2').create(credentials);

const tokenConfig = {
  username: 'uuuuuu@dddddd.com',
  password: 'ppppppp',
  scope: process.env.APP_SCOPES,
};

try {
  const result = await oauth2.ownerPassword.getToken(tokenConfig);
  const accessToken = oauth2.accessToken.create(result);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Access Token Error', error.message);
}
exports.accessToken = accessToken;
```

When I try to start website, nodejs shows me a sintax error:

```
const result = await oauth2.ownerPassword.getToken(tokenConfig);
               ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

This error does not make much sense to me since the code is provided by simple-oauth2.

Could someone shed light on my actual error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have to wrap your code into `async` function so you could use `await` key word in that function. You cna find more info [here](https://javascript.info/async-await).

In your case I would wrap code into function and export that function like this:

```
const credentials = {
  client: {
    id: process.env.APP_ID,
    secret: process.env.APP_PASSWORD,
  },
  auth: {
    tokenHost: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
    authorizePath: "common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
    tokenPath: "common/oauth2/v2.0/token",
  }
};
const oauth2 = require('simple-oauth2').create(credentials);

const tokenConfig = {
  username: 'uuuuuu@dddddd.com',
  password: 'ppppppp',
  scope: process.env.APP_SCOPES,
};

const getAccessToken = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await oauth2.ownerPassword.getToken(tokenConfig);
    const accessToken = oauth2.accessToken.create(result);
    return accessToken;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Access Token Error', error.message);
    return null;
  }
};

exports.getAccessToken = getAccessToken;
```

And then you can use that function like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var authHelper = require('../helpers/auth');

router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  let parms = { title: 'Home', active: { home: true } };
  const accessToken = await authHelper.getAccessToken();
  res.render('index', parms);
});

module.exports = router;
```